# .NET - Lower Application Privileges

Tags: c#, privileges, sandbox

I would like to know how to programmatically lower my application's privileges.  So, let's say someone with admin privileges runs my program, I would like my program to still run under a normal user's environment or with less privileges that I don't need.  Also, could you explain what is restricted in the lower trust environment?

**Edit:**   Curtisk suggested the permview.exe tool to view an application's permissions, which lead me in the right direction to the **newer permcalc.exe tool** - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165077(VS.80).aspx.  Thanks again.

Comment: Good question, looking forward to an answer.

Comment: ah ha! I did link to old framework 1.0-1.1 version didn't I? Good catch and update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The RequestMinimum Flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229913.aspx) may be close to what you need, although it is zone/PermissionSet based, more details in the linked MSDN How-to.

The idea is it will run the application with the least set of privileges to function, regardless of who calls it...

**Follow up on question in comments below:** check out the [Permissions View Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06251f13.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Curtisk!  Is there any way to find a list of all privileges available and all privileges my application uses, so that I can turn off the privilege I don't need?

Comment: Thanks...you got me 90% of the way there.  See editing original post.